# Type 'GLchar' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, freeglut, glew

I'm using Eclipse, MinGW, and I have compiled freeglut and glew and copied their libraries, DLLs, and header files into the proper locations (MinGW/include/GL, MinGW/lib, Windows/SysWOW64). I have also linked the libraries (freeglut64, opengl32, glew32, glu32) in Eclipse under the MinGW C++ Linker. Here is my code...

```
--CharGame.cpp--
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "CharGame.h"
#define WINDOW_TITLE "CharGame"

int CurrentWidth = 800,
    CurrentHeight = 600,
    WindowHandle = 0;
unsigned FrameCount = 0;
GLuint VertexShaderId,
    FragmentShaderId,
    ProgramId,
    VaoId,
    VboId,
    ColorBufferId;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Initialize(argc, argv);
    glutMainLoop();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
const GLchar* VertexShader =
{
    "#version 400\n"\

    "layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;\n"\
    "layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;\n"\
    "out vec4 ex_Color;\n"\

    "void main(void)\n"\
    "{\n"\
    "   gl_Position = in_Position;\n"\
    "   ex_Color = in_Color;\n"\
    "}\n"
};
const GLchar* FragmentShader =
{
    "#version 400\n"\

    "in vec4 ex_Color;\n"\
    "out vec4 out_Color;\n"\

    "void main(void)\n"\
    "{\n"\
    "   out_Color = ex_Color;\n"\
    "}\n"
};

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);
    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);
    if (WindowHandle < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not create a render window.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glutReshapeFunc(Resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(Render);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);
    glutTimerFunc(0, Timer, 0);

    fprintf(stdout, "Info: OpenGL Version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

}

void Resize(int width, int height) {
    CurrentHeight = height;
    CurrentWidth = width;
    glViewport(0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
}

void Render(void) {
    ++FrameCount;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void Idle(void) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void Timer(int value) {
    if (0 != value) {
        char* TempString = (char*) malloc(512 + strlen(WINDOW_TITLE));
        sprintf(TempString, "%s: %d Frames Per Second @ %d x %d", WINDOW_TITLE, FrameCount*4, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
        glutSetWindowTitle(TempString);
        free(TempString);
    }
    FrameCount = 0;
    glutTimerFunc(250, Timer, 1);
}
--End CharGame.cpp--

--CharGame.h--
#ifndef CHARGAME_H_
#define CHARGAME_H_

void Initialize(int, char*[]);
void InitWindow(int, char*[]);
void Resize(int,int);
void Render(void);
void Timer(int);
void Idle(void);

#endif
--End CharGame.h--
```

I believe I have done everything right, however, Eclipse throws the error "Type 'GLchar' could not be resolved" on VertexShader and FragmentShader. Did I make a mistake in my code or miss a required step?

Comment: Have you tried including `<GL/gl.h>`?

Comment: Yes I have. I have tried including that along with everything else in the GL/ folder, and it still throws the error.

Answer (score 2):

You're not declaring string constants the right way. You don't need curly braces there. And watch out for empty lines betwreen the strings - either remove them (see below) or add the "\" there.

Include the "GL/GL.h" file before "glew.h", this might help also.

Use this with ordinary chars:

```
const char* VertexShader =
"#version 400\n"\
"layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;\n"\
"layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;\n"\
"out vec4 ex_Color;\n"\
"void main(void)\n"\
"{\n"\
"   gl_Position = in_Position;\n"\
"   ex_Color = in_Color;\n"\
"}\n";

const char* FragmentShader =
"#version 400\n"\
"in vec4 ex_Color;\n"\
"out vec4 out_Color;\n"\
"void main(void)\n"\
"{\n"\
"   out_Color = ex_Color;\n"\
"}\n";
```

Comment: Tried that before, and I just tried it now. It still throws the error. :/

Comment: "const char*" works. However, I believe it needs to be GLchar* to work with OpenGL/Freeglut/GLEW.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be. GLuint and other such stuff is just a straightforward typedef over the int and other types.

Comment: So it works and the answer can be accepted or you need some extra help with this ?

Comment: also there's no need for the backslashes because the newline it's escaping doesn't mean anything anyway. And if the compiler supports it you can use raw strings and avoid the escaped new lines inside the string literal and all those extra quotes. I'll show an example in an 'answer'.

Comment: Yeah, backslashes are mostly useful when controlling the preprocessor (which does care about newlines).  But string combining is done by the compiler, not the preprocessor, and will occur whether the strings are separated by horizontal space, newlines, or any other whitespace.

Comment: Guys, believe me :) I really wanted to remove the backslashes :) It was just about the erroneous curly braces and the GLchar type.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov: "No, it doesn't need to be. GLuint and other such stuff is just a straightforward typedef over the int and other types." No, they aren't. They are specific types that have a particular size which, for a particular implementation of OpenGL, matches what the implementation expects. Just because you can *sometimes* get away with using the wrong types doesn't mean that you *should*.

Comment: I wanted to add about "sizeof() warranties" for GLuint/GLfloat. Just because the question was about "const char*" there was no need to emphasize the other types.

Comment: This advice is completely wrong. GLEW should always be included _first_ before any other OpenGL header.

Answer (score 1):

This is just expanding on my comment on another answer:

```
const char* VertexShader =
R"(#version 400
layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;
layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;
out vec4 ex_Color;
void main(void)
{
   gl_Position = in_Position;
   ex_Color = in_Color;
}
)";
```

Comment: I fixed it. I had to right-click on the Project in the Project Explorer, go to Index, then Rebuild and Freshen All Files. It works now.