# Failed to load model with assimp, access violation

Tags: c++, opengl, access-violation, assimp

I got a problem when I want to import a simple model using assimp, whenever I compile the code it throws:

`0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

I know this is something about a null pointer but I just can't find it, the code goes as follows:

```
Model::Model(GLchar* path)
{
    loadModel(path);
}

void Model::loadModel(std::string path)
{
    Assimp::Importer import;
    const aiScene* scene = import.ReadFile(
        path, 
        aiProcess_Triangulate | 
        aiProcess_FlipUVs);

    if (!scene || scene->mFlags == AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode){
        std::cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP::" << import.GetErrorString() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));

    aiNode* node = scene->mRootNode;
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++){
        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        meshes.push_back(processMesh(mesh, scene));
    }

    for (GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++){
        processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
    }
}
```

I use this Model class as a global variable:

```
//include stuff

//other global variable
Model mymodel("D:/Project/xxx/xxx.obj");

int main(){
//...
return 0;
}
```

The thing is that the error happens just between the line `directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));` and the line `aiNode* node = scene->mRootNode;` so I don't know how to debug it, could anyone tell me how to fix this? I use Visual Studio 2013-64 and assimp-3.1.1.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you not checking for `node` being NULL?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie both the `node` and the `scene->mRootNode` is not NULL

Comment: *so I don't know how to debug it,*  -- How did you know where the error occurred if you're not debugging it?  Also `directory` isn't used anywhere.  Last, are you debugging an optimized build?  If so, then you're not going to synch up the line of code with the actual code that is being executed.  Oh, and you really should use API functions (`Pathxxx` functions defined in shlwapi.lib, for example) to split path names into their components.

Comment: You're iterating through `[0; node->mNumChildren)`, but accessing `node->mMeshes[i]`, which is in range `[0; node->mNumMeshes)`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie First thanks for your help. I wrote this code based on an online [tutorial](http://learnopengl.com/#!Model-Loading/Model), the `directory` will be used in the `processMesh()` function and that looks not the problem. I made a breakpoint at `directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));` and debug the code step by step and it stops at the next blank line. And if I press F11 it doesn't goes to anywhere, how to slove such problem?

Comment: @keltar Oops, that's it, my bad, thank you very very much!

Comment: @PandaChen Can you explain? (You can also answer your own question.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in this part of the code:

```
Model::Model(GLchar* path)
{    
    loadModel(path); // path is declared a string in loadModel function - type conversion might not be happening as expected.
}
```

Check, if you are getting a correct/valid value in the path variable on the line:

```
directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));
```

This link might be helpful:
[GLchar could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886056/type-glchar-could-not-be-resolved)

Note: I am not familiar with OpenGL, but looking at the error you are getting this is the first place I would check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have checked that before and that is not the problem.